# Opacity on background image

Tags: html, css, background-image, opacity

As far as I know I can't directly change the opacity of a background image but using `::before` and `::after` doesn't seem to let my image show up. Am I doing it wrong?
HTML

### **flower window boxes**

All of our products come in virtually any length up to 16 feet and two sizes.  Our standard size boxes are designed to accommodate almost any flower.  Our XL sizes are taller and deeper to provide more root space for plants making them the ideal sized window boxes for plants.

```
    </div>
    <div class="card-back">
        <h2 class="click-here"><b>Visit Site</b></h2>
        <div class="info">
        <h2 class="info">Email:</h2>
        <h2 class="info">Phone:</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="all-content">
        <h1>Contrary to popular belief</h1>
    </div>
</li>
```

Current CSS

```
 .content li:nth-child(1) .card-back{
            background-image:url(../images/sponsor-imgs/Cellular%20PVC%20Columns-Kingston-1.jpg);
       width: 100%;}
```

What I've tried

```
.backimg::after {
    background-image:url(../images/backimg/wide.png);
      opacity: 0.5;
}
.backimg::before{
        background-image:url(../images/backimg/wide.png);
          opacity: 0.5;
    }
div::after {

  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

On a side not i know i can simply make the images themselves transparent, but i feel like a code to do it much more useful in the long run. thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no element in your dom with class .backimg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::before` and `::after` require a `content` property. You can set it to an empty string but it *must* be included.

In most cases you also need to define a `display` property and assign some dimensions to the element (unless you are using something like `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` - in which case, you don't).

```css
.backimg {
  background: red;
}

.backimg::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200x200);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="backimg"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You are missing the .backimg class in your html.

Dont use double :: and add content and display properties to after. Also some dimensions wouldnt hourt (width,height)

```
.class:after{
    Cintent:"";
    Display:block; // change as you see fit

}
```